# Search by a word in jsp

Tags: javascript, java, mysql, database, jsp

Hello i got those pages:

DistributieFilm.java

package filme;

```
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.PreparedStatement;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class DistributieFilm {

    public static ArrayList<Film> getFilme() {

        ArrayList<Film> listaFilm = new ArrayList<Film>();
        PreparedStatement stm = null;
        ResultSet rs = null;
        Connection conn = null;
        String query = "SELECT  * FROM imdbutil.filme WHERE film_nume=?";

        try {
            conn = DbUtil.getConnection();
            stm = conn.prepareStatement(query);
            rs = stm.executeQuery();

            while (rs.next()) {

                Film lista = new Film();

                lista.setId(rs.getInt("film_id"));
                lista.setNume(rs.getString("film_nume"));
                lista.setRegizor(rs.getString("film_regizor"));
                lista.setDatalansarii(rs.getString("film_datalansarii"));

                listaFilm.add(lista);
            }

        } catch (SQLException e) {
            //
            System.out.println(e.getMessage());
        } catch (Exception e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            DbUtil.closeAll(rs, stm, conn);
        }

        return listaFilm;
    }

}
```

Film.class

```
package filme;

public class Film {

    private int film_id;
    private String film_nume;
    private String film_regizor;
    private String film_datalansarii;

    public Film(String nume, String regizor, String datalansarii) {
        this.film_nume = nume;
        this.film_regizor = regizor;
        this.film_datalansarii = datalansarii;
    }

    public Film() {
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }

    public int getId() {
        return film_id;
    }
    public String getNume() {
        return film_nume;
    }
    public String getRegizor() {
        return film_regizor;
    }
    public String getDatalansarii() {
        return film_datalansarii;
    }
    public void setId(int id) {
        this.film_id = id;
    }
    public void setNume(String nume) {
        this.film_nume = nume;
    }
    public void setRegizor(String regizor) {
        this.film_regizor = regizor;
    }
    public void setDatalansarii(String datalansarii) {
        this.film_datalansarii = datalansarii;
    }
}
```

And cautare.jsp

```
    <%@page import="java.util.*"%>
    <%@page import="filme.*"%>
    <%@page import="java.sql.*"%>

    <html>

    <body>
        <%
        Film filmNoua = new Film(request.getParameter("film_nume"),request.getParameter("film_regizor"),request.getParameter("film_datalansarii"));

        ArrayList<Film> listaFilm = DistributieFilm.getFilme();
        %>

    <center>
    <table border="1">
        <tr>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><b><font color="#ffffff">Id</td></font>
            <td><b><font color="#ffffff">Nume</td></font>
            <td><b><font color="#ffffff">Regizor</td></font>
            <td><b><font color="#ffffff">Data Lansarii</td></font>

        </tr>

        <%
            for (Film lista : listaFilm) {

        %>
        <tr>
            <td><font color="#ff0000"><%=lista.getId()%></td></font>
            <td><font color="#ff99ff"><%=lista.getNume()%></td></font>
            <td><font color="#bb0fff"><%=lista.getRegizor()%></td></font>
            <td><font color="#ffggff"><%=lista.getDatalansarii()%></td></font>
        </tr>
        <%
            }
        %>
        <tr>
        <td><a href="inserare.jsp"><input type="button" value="Insereaza un nou film"></a></td>
        <tr>
    </table>
</center>
</body>


</html>
```

My question is, how i can search by name a movie that i got in database (i have 5 movies and i want to search 1 and show it . p.s i got a search.jsp too where i add a text word for search)

Thanks

Comment: Are you getting any errors or something? This is basically just a code dump, nothing to go upon in your question.

Comment: when i search let's say with this word "test"  i get all the 5 movies and not the movie with "test" name and only this.

Answer (score 1):

You have to pass in your filter criteria to your DAO class `DistributieFilm`; modify `getFilme` to accept `filmNoua` as a parameter.

Set the criteria to your statement

```
stm.setString(1, filmNoua.getName());
rs = stm.executeQuery();
```